# Nested if conditions issue

Tags: php

I have this part of code which i use in order to prevent query submission twice! Now, this is the query i use in order to make it work, and it works.

```
    $form_secret = isset($_POST["form_secret"])?$_POST["form_secret"]:'';    
    $query = "INSERT INTO coupon (user_id,points) VALUES ('$user_id','$points')";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    if ($points == 250) 
    { 
       $url="http://testext.i-movo.com/api/receivesms.aspx?".$str_from.$str_zip.$phone.$str_time.$date1.$str_msg;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    }
    else if ($points == 500) 
    {
        $url="http://testext.i-movo.com/api/receivesms.aspx?".$str_from.$str_zip.$phone.$str_time.$date1.$str_msg;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "We are sorry, you don't possess enough points in order to take the coupon";   
    }
```

Perfect up to now!
What i need then is to prevent double submission and hence i'm using this code here, but the problem is, when i put all the above code inside this one, it doesn't work.. anyone please tell me how to unite this two codes? Thanks..

```
if(isset($_SESSION["FORM_SECRET"])) 
{
    if(strcasecmp($form_secret, $_SESSION["FORM_SECRET"]) === 0) 
    {
        /*Put your form submission code here after processing the form data, unset the secret key from the session*/
        unset($_SESSION["FORM_SECRET"]);
    }
    else 
    {
        //Invalid secret key
    }
} 
else 
{
    //Secret key missing
    echo "Form data has already been processed!";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean *doesn't work*?

Comment: It means if i do refresh it still submits the form.. again.. i mean the code above preventing submission works, and the code above it, i just can't put them together, i guess for sure there might be something with the syntax of if, else if etc etc..

Comment: there's no starting if in your forst code snippet

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't understand...

Comment: Did u mean you wanted to avoid re-submission of the same data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SESSION["FORM_SECRET"]` will not be set by default, so you can never submit the form in the first place.

Reverse the process. Give the form a secret key, and store that secret in the session when the form is submitted. Then, on the next submit, you can check if `$_SESSION["FORM_SECRET"]` is set (and is the same as the submitted secret), so you'll know that it's the second submit of the same form.

Comment: `$_SESSION` is session information. Do you mean `$_POST`, or are you mixing things up?